# ANDROID: Need help getting debugging key to set up maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Please don't just link to the google tutorial for this like the majority of questions seem to because I have already gone through it. I am asking because I am stuck.

I am trying to get my debug key -- I have tried the terminal commands.  I get told that the file /.android/debug.keystore does not exist by the terminal. Furthermore I cannot SEE the .android folder AT ALL.

Oh -- And I'm using OSX Lion

Help?

Comment: `I get told that the file /.android/debug.keystore does not exist.` - by whom?  The dearth of information here is mind boggling - throw us a bone please

Answer (score 0):

What OS? On Linux .android is in your home directory, so you need something like `cd ~/.android` to go there. On Windows it should be in `%USERPROFILE%` or `%APPDATA%`.